# null pointer exception on getApplicationContext()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I tried the following code with extend activity it worked perfect but now i changed the code to work with extending fragment. I search thorugh internet and found `getActivity()` function to call `query()` and other functions. I tried this but now it gives an error saying:

**Error**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.funtube_mp4/com.example.admin.funtube_mp4.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.admin.funtube_mp4.HomeFragmant.init_phone_video_grid(HomeFragmant.java:65)
            at com.example.admin.funtube_mp4.HomeFragmant.onCreateView(HomeFragmant.java:49)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5550)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**code**

```
public class HomeFragmant extends Fragment{
    private Cursor videocursor;
    private int video_column_index;
    ListView videolist;

    List<String> listpath = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] paths=new String[100];
    int count;
    String[] thumbColumns = { MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID };
    String path;
    File file;

    public HomeFragmant() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        videolist = (ListView) getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.PhoneVideoList);
        init_phone_video_grid();

        return rootView;

    }
    private void init_phone_video_grid() {
        System.gc();
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };

      //  file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Funtube/UserData/Videos/");
       // videocursor =getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? ", new String[]{"%" + file.getAbsolutePath().toString() + "%"}, null);
        videocursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);
//        videocursor =getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? ", new String[]{"%" + file.getAbsolutePath().toString() + "%"}, null);

        count = videocursor.getCount();

        videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        videolist.setOnItemClickListener(videogridlistener);
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener videogridlistener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
            System.gc();
            video_column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String filename = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ViewVideo.class);
            intent.putExtra("videofilename", filename);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context vContext;

        public VideoAdapter(Context c) {
            vContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            System.gc();
            ViewHolder holder;
            String id = null;
            convertView = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(vContext).inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                holder.txtSize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSize);
                holder.thumbImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);

                video_column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
                id = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
                video_column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);
                videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
                // id += " Size(KB):" +
                // videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
                holder.txtTitle.setText(id);
                holder.txtSize.setText(" Size(KB):"+ videocursor.getString(video_column_index));

                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{id}, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                long ids = cursor.getLong(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));

                ContentResolver crThumb = getActivity().getContentResolver();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 1;
                Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                        crThumb, ids, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                        options);
                holder.thumbImage.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
                curThumb = null;

            } /*
             * else holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
             */
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtSize;
        ImageView thumbImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally agree with @2Dee   and may be you have to try with  only  **getActivity()**

```
videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getActivity()));
```

Comment: I tried this and it helped me but now it is not showing video on HomeFragment

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `getActivity()` in `onCreateView`, you have no guarantee that the `Activity` is fully created there. Use the `onActivityCreated` method to get a reference to your `Activity`.

And unless you're afraid of leaking the `Activity`, you could just use `getActivity()`, no need to retrieve the ApplicationContext to create your Adapter IMHO.

From the [docs about Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

> Caution: If you need a Context object within your Fragment, you can
>   call getActivity(). However, be careful to call getActivity() only
>   when the fragment is attached to an activity. When the fragment is not
>   yet attached, or was detached during the end of its lifecycle,
>   getActivity() will return null.

Comment: I tried your code but now it isn't showing the video list? Is my adapter code correct?

Comment: Check if your adapter actually contains data.

Comment: `public View onActivityCreated(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` This line comes in light gray color. I think this isn't working

Comment: That's not a correct override of the method (it should return void, not a View object), please do read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)). Unless you have a compelling reason not to, let your IDE and auto-complete write method overrides for you...

Comment: I used void but it will not return the rootview

Comment: Again, please **read the docs**. The method in your comment above has too many arguments, it only takes on Bundle object, no LayoutInflater or ViewGroup... If your override is incorrect, delete it and have Android Studio generate it for you, that way it will only generate a proper override of the method.

Comment: Also, getting a reference to a View in your Activity (in your case, the ListView) from the Fragment is not good design, I recommend you spend the time to read the documentation and maybe a book about Android (Reto Meier's is pretty good) to learn how to properly create and handle Activity and Fragment, how each one interact with the other etc...